# How can I return Generic Class Object in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, return-value

I'm working on one Project where I Export data from different sources and want to save in common format.
here is my c# Lib code will be look like, This will use to provide Common table list and Classes and Also provide Writer object based on Selected FileType.

```
namespace CommonLib
{
public class Table1
{
    // properties
}

public class Table2
{
    // properties
}

public class Table3
{
    // properties
}
..many other tables



public enum FileType
{
Csv,
Zip,
....
}


public interface IWriter<T>:IDisposable
{
    string GetTableName();
    void WriteLine(T data);
    void WriteLine(IDataReader reader);
    void WriteObject(IDataReader reader);
    void WriteObject(IEnumerable<T> dataList);
    int GetRowCount();
}


class CsvWriter<T>:IWriter<T>
{
    public CsvWriter(){ //constructor body }
    public string GetTableName(){ //method body }
    public void WriteLine(T data){ //method body }
    public void WriteLine(IDataReader reader){ //method body }
    public void WriteObject(IDataReader reader){ //method body }
    public void WriteObject(IEnumerable<T> dataList){ //method body }
    public int GetRowCount(){ //method body }
    public void Dispose(){ // body }
}

class ZipWriter<T>:IWriter<T>
{
    public CsvWriter(){ //constructor body }
    public string GetTableName(){ //method body }
    public void WriteLine(T data){ //method body }
    public void WriteLine(IDataReader reader){ //method body }
    public void WriteObject(IDataReader reader){ //method body }
    public void WriteObject(IEnumerable<T> dataList){ //method body }
    public int GetRowCount(){ //method body }
    public void Dispose(){ // body }
}

public class Writer<T>:IWriter<T>
{
    IWriter<T> writer;
    public Writer(FileType fileType)
    {
        writer=new Object based on FileType
    }
    public string GetTableName(){ writer.GetTableName(); }
    public void WriteLine(T data){ writer.WriteLine(data); }
    public void WriteLine(IDataReader reader){ writer.WriteLine(reader); }
    public void WriteObject(IDataReader reader){ writer.WriteObject(reader); }
    public void WriteObject(IEnumerable<T> dataList){ writer.WriteObject(dataList); }
    public int GetRowCount(){ return writer.GetRowCount(); }
    public void Dispose(){ // body }
}

public class Helper
{
public static List<string> GetTableList()
{
    return new List<string>(){"Table1","Table2","Table3",....};
}

public static IWriter<T> GetWriterObject(string tableName,FileType fileType)
{
    switch(tableName)
    {
        case "Table1":
            return new Writer<Table1>(fileType);
        case "Table2":
            return new Writer<Table2>(fileType);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
}

}
```

Here is my UI App code logic will be where i will use above Lib.

```
namespace MyApp
{
    class MainForm()
    {
        void Load()
        {
            var tableList=Helper.GetTableList();
            // bind this list in UI with multi Select option, User can select any table

        }

        void button_click()
        {
            // Get Selected tables
            // Get selected Filetype
            foreach( var fname in SelectedTableList)
            {
                var wObject=Helper.GetWriterObject(fname,fileType);
                wObject.WriteObject(GetReader(fname));
            }
        }
        IDataReader GetReader(string tablename)
        {   
        // return reader
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to know How I can get Writer Object by Passing String File Name and FileType?

`var wObject=Helper.GetWriterObject(fname,fileType);`

I dont want to return OBJECT DataType. I need Strong type object.

Thanks

Comment: Try to create BaseTable and inherit this in all table1,2 and 3 then try..

Comment: you are probably looking for an IoC container like Autofac.

Comment: You either need to make `GetWriterObject` generic and call it with a generic argument (if you know beforehand what type it will return), or you can't do exactly what you want to do and need to return a non-generic interface.  At the point of use, generics require you to know the type parameters at compile-time; this is the defining feature of generics. (There are reflection-based tricks you can use to instantiate generic types at run-time, but these still need to go into a non-generic return type.)